# For what start value does Newton's method converge?

Tags: newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

I have the equation $f(x)=1/x-a=0$ and I need to find necessary and sufficient conditions for the start value $x_0$ so that the method converges.

First I set up the sequence $x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}=-ax_k^2+2x_k$ (Is this correct?)
Now for convergence I thought that $\frac{||x_{k+1}-\frac{1}{a}||}{||x_k-\frac{1}{a}||}$ has to be less than 1 (1/a in this case is the exact solution of the equation). Is this true? And if so, how would I show that? Also how could I then derive conditions for the initial value $x_0$?

Comment: Did you write down $\frac{||x_{k+1}-\frac{1}{a}||}{||x_k-\frac{1}{a}||}$ with $\,x_{k+1} = -ax_k^2+2x_k\,$ and try to simplify it? How far did you get?

Comment: Have you tried some actual *examples* to get a feel for yourself first about what the answer might be.  After all, your question is about a numerical algorithm, not an abstract theorem. Carry it out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numerical Methods: calculate $b/a$ without division](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186607/numerical-methods-calculate-b-a-without-division)

Comment: I added a reference to a related question whose answer solves your problem.